# Angular Change the HTML string ( from backend API in form of string ) into image and show that image into the angular mat-card

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ckeditor, html-to-image

I'm working on this project where i'm using CK editor to generate the template and it is saving the HTML string in nodejs and at get api i'm getting the html string which i want to show in mat-card as in form of image
i tried html-to-image by i'm getting problem with its input type as it is not accepting html string , is there any way to change the html string into the image and show that image to mat-card , i'll really apreaciate your help..

i tried changing html string into dom file and i also tried changing into base64 and i aslo tried html-to-image package i'm not getting any near as they are not generating the URL to show the image ,

i'm expecting a way in same as these to do so

Comment: what are you using to convert to image? [html-to-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image)? Please, update your question indicate what library do you use and what code have you try executed

Answer (score 0):

Could you share some code snippet, probably a stackblitz? Its hard to understand without seeing the code.